# Set up SVN Server over https

Tags: linux, apache, svn

I'm trying to get an SVN server up and running.  CentOS 6.4, apache 2.2.15.  More importantly, I need to have it running on https only.  So I figure that I'll get ssl running first, as I've already tested it on port 80, and SVN works the way I want it to.

In /etc/httpd/ssl, I have ..

intermediate.crt  wildcard.mycompany.com.crt  wildcard.mycompany.com.key

We bought a wildcard certificate from GeoTrust, and I downloaded the intermediate.crt from their website.  In /etc/httpd/httpd.conf, I have..

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my.email@mycompany.com
        ServerName hostname.mycompany.com
        ErrorLog logs/error_log
        CustomLog logs/access_log common
        Redirect permanent / https://hostname.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost hostname.mycompany.com:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard.mycompany.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard.mycompany.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/intermediate.crt
        ServerName hostname.mycompany.com
        ServerAdmin my.email@mycompany.com
        ErrorLog logs/subversion-error_log
        CustomLog logs/subversion-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I can connect to the server, but my browser tells me that the certificate is untrusted.  So I'm guessing that there's an error in the permissions, or perhaps in the format of the file?

I can't see anything in the logs.

I set this up at home on my own server, but wasn't using a wildcard certificate.

Anyone care to advise as to what's gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that question is maybe better asked at serverfault. It also seems that the question should be "how to configure apache to accept my wildcard certificate" (the actual problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with Subversion really).

Comment: Got SVN working over http, and the root works via both 80 and 443.  SVN still doesn't want to behave, however, so a new question needs to be asked..